# How java compiles adding operation of Strings to using StringAppend and how can one define operation behavior of self-created object like this

Tags: java, string, char

----------Updated-------

I thought it won't be that straightway but it turned out that it can just work in that way seamlessly.

It just works for the car `String a = "abc" + 'c';` as well as `String a = "abc" + "a";`

I looked into source codes of both String and CharSequence class but haven't found the exact method that enables this scenario.

Also, I have doubted that there might be something like override of the "+" plus operator for String or char but I have no idea where to search for the clues.

I doubted in this way because I am also a python user for a few years and there exists the scenario of overriding the magic functions like `python 
__add__` which defines the action of an object when it acts as the operand of "+" or add operation.
I just want to know where I can find the clue of java compiling `String a = "abc" + 'c';`  into using the `StringBuilder.append()`. I just want to see where this process takes place.
But knowing this I think I can know how to enable act of self-created objects when they are operands of some basic operation.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: What does being able to concatenate `char` with `String` has to do with `Character[][]` to `char[][]` conversion?

Comment: can you give what will be sample input and output?

Comment: 'I have doubted that there might be something like override of the "+" plus operator for String or char': you have 'doubted this' why? '... but I have no idea where to search for the clues.' Really? Have you considered consulting the Java Language Specification?

Comment: @user207421 I know I am starter both with java and here, so my question may seem dumb. I usually get lost in the java language specs and cannot find my way easily because English is not my first language. Also, as I have updated I doubted in the way due to the fact overriding magic methods like `__add__` in python can defining the behavior of objects when it is doing add action. Which seems similar to me considering string concatenation in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked into source codes of both String and CharSequence class but haven't found the exact method that enables this scenario.

You are looking in the wrong place.

> Also, I have doubted that there might be something like override of the "+" plus operator for String or char but I have no idea where to search for the clues.

The places to look are:

- The bytecodes emitted by the bytecode compiler.  You can examine them using the `javap` command.  Use the `-c` option to see the disassembled bytecodes.
- The Java Language Specification (JLS) says what `+` means exactly, and explains how a Java compiler is permitted to convert `+` into a variety of different sequences of calls to `String` methods.  The section to read is [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)
- The source code of the Java compiler itself; i.e. `javac` or a 3rd-party equivalent.  That will give the *definitive* logic that the compiler uses when deciding how to translate the string `+` operator.

---

Actually, the above applies to Java 8 and earlier.  In Java 9 / JEP 280, they changed things to use `invokedynamic` to express concatenation sequences so that the JIT compiler has more freedom to optimize the actual calling sequences.   See:

- [JDK 9/JEP 280: String Concatenations Will Never Be the Same](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9jep-280-string-concatenations-will-never-be-t)
- [JEP 280 - Indify String Concatenation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)

In Java 9 or later, you would need to look at the native code emitted by the JIT compiler to see how a concatenation is actually implemented.

---

> Also, as I have updated I doubted in the way due to the fact overriding magic methods like `__add__` in python can defining the behavior of objects when it is doing add action. Which seems similar to me considering string concatenation in java.

Do not try to understand the Java implementation in terms of your knowledge of Python.  The languages and their implementations are **very** different.  For a start, there Java has no equivalent to Python's `__` methods (apart from `__init__`).  Java applications cannot overload operators.

Instead, read the Java language and virtual machine specifications.

Comment: Yeah I see, I am looking into incorrect places. But I am really not conscious  that there is the JLS, maybe because that in Chinese network people don't talk about it frequently.  But  I am still wondering is there a way I can define the `+` action of my own object so that it looks just like `int +  int`?

Comment: You can't.  Java does not support operator overloading.  Period.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try to understand them seperately  and thanks a lot for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler transparently converts expressions like

```
String str3 = str1 + str2;
```

to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str1).append(str2);
str3 = sb.toString();
```

Since `StringBuilder` has matching methods for many data types including `char` it is possible to concatenate String and char using the + operator.